# Why can't add a character at the beginning of each line in the edited article?

Tags: substitute, replace

```
:set lcs=precedes:^,eol:#
```

I want to insert a character **^**  at the beginning of each line.
Here is the result of **:set lcs=precedes:^,eol:#**.

[image]

Why **lcs=precedes:^** can't add a character **^** in the article such as the following?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To add `^` at the beginning of each line use

`:%s/^/^ /`

For a range of lines use:

Ex. Lines 10-20    -   `:10,20s/^/^ /`

Comment: i want to make **set list** take the same effect such as ** :%s/^/^ /** do.

Answer (score 2):

As per VIM Help on `listchars`, `precedes:^` only results in `^` showing at the beginning of the line if "`'wrap'` is off and there is text preceding the character visible in the first column."

So `precedes` provides an indication that the first character shown on the screen is not the first character in the line. In terms of `listchars` options, it is the start-of-line equivalent of `extends`, which indicates that the line continues beyond the right of the screen when `wrap` is off.

There is no start-of-line equivalent of `eol` – that is, an option that would show a virtual character preceding the first character in the line. There is no need for that as you always know where the line starts (at the left edge of the screen, unless `precedes` indicates otherwise), while you don't always know where the line ends if you have trailing whitespace.